# Is there a view for a button bar? (Image link describing the view)

Tags: android

I am looking for a view or some sort of information regarding the bottom bar in default applications of Android such as Email, or Unlock pattern as shown in the picture below. I have not been able find anything about this on Androids site nor from Google searches.

Image: http://img11.imageshack.us/i/viewdn.jpg/

Comment: i call duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127459/which-android-control-to-use/2224638

Answer (score 7):

I believe that Christopher is correct; there is no special widget to create the bar in your image.  However, if you want to emulate it, you can create a layout and use the style `style="@android:style/ButtonBar"`.  That will give you the light gray background and the correct margins.

Comment: Cool! Hadn't seen that style before. Yet Google don't bother using it in their own apps (well, from the few layouts I looked at)..

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's any standard view for the button bar used at the bottom of these apps; it's generally just two `Button` items placed together in a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

For example, looking at the [Android Open Source Project](http://android.git.kernel.org/), you can see the [button bar for one of the email app setup screens](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=blob;f=res/layout/account_setup_basics.xml;h=0603be5cae3272111da69acae7d2b30320ab63f3;hb=HEAD#l72) is defined as two plain old [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) objects.

However, it is surprising that Google didn't abstract more of the common stuff into an Android theme or sublayout, rather than having the same views and attributes in each layout XML.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/trunk/res/layout/account_setup_basics.xml?r=1314

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dip" 
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|right" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/manual_setup"
            android:text="@string/account_setup_basics_manual_setup_action"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/button_minWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false" 
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:text="@string/next_action"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/button_minWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/button_indicator_next"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false" 
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```