# Help for basic Android view for a Next/Prev navigation like E-mail setup

Tags: java, xml, android, layout, view

[http://www.lboro.ac.uk/it/google/android-images/image002.jpg http://www.lboro.ac.uk/it/google/android-images/image002.jpg](http://www.lboro.ac.uk/it/google/android-images/image002.jpg)

I am after the XML view code, just like the E-mail setup.
How can I put on that bottom grey bar that Next button, how about a Prev button on left side?

Comment: Your URL appears inaccessible. Anyway, this seems to have been already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989595/is-there-a-view-for-a-button-bar-image-link-describing-the-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/browse/k9mail/trunk/res/layout/account_setup_basics.xml?r=1314

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-45dip" 
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom|right" 
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/manual_setup"
            android:text="@string/account_setup_basics_manual_setup_action"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/button_minWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false" 
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:text="@string/next_action"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/button_minWidth"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/button_indicator_next"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false" 
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```